# How to combine tags as long as they have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The Html that I'm getting **ideally** looks like this:

```
<span class="RapidLink1-H">See the more detailed areas of what not</span>
```

Next my aim is to change the span tag into an anchor tag. With the ideal Html, I have done it this way:

```
            // Walk through each link tag on this page and replace the content with an actual link
            thisLink.each(function() {

                linkRefTarget = '';

                // Get only the identifier number of the link
                linkId = ($(this).attr('class')).replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, '');

                // Match this link with the list of link references
                if (thisLinkRef) {
                    for (var key in thisLinkRef) {
                        if (key == 'link' + linkId) linkRefTarget = thisLinkRef[key];
                    }
                }

                output = '';
                output+= '<a href="#' + linkRefTarget + '" id="link' + linkId + '" class="rapidLink">';
                output+= $(this).html();
                output+= '</a>';

            }).replaceWith(output);
```

Now, the problem comes when I'm actually getting this sort of Html (please note, I can't change the Html input):

```
<span class="RapidLink1-H">See the</span><span class="RapidLink1-H">more detailed areas of</span><span class="RapidLink1-H">what not</span></span>
```

The question is:

**How could I get it to work with such a broken set of spans?**

I'm thinking the following:

- Find an expected link span
- Check whether the immediate next element is also a span with the same class
- and then check whether the immediate next element is also...,
- and then check...
- if none is found, combine the innerHtml of each span into a single anchor tag

How could I achieve such a loop?

Thanks.

Comment: I know DOM manipulation with regexes are not done, but I would almost advice replacing all `</span><span class="RapidLink1-H">` in your HTML. It sounds a lot easier than the idea you put up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `+` selector which selects consecutive elements: http://jsfiddle.net/NWWYC/1/.

```
$(".RapidLink1-H + .RapidLink1-H").each(function() {
    // move contents to previous span, remove this span afterwards
    $(this).prev(".RapidLink1-H").append(
        $(this).contents()
    ).end().remove();
});
```

Comment: what is the difference between `$(this).contents()` and `$(this).html()`

Comment: @Dariush Jafari: `.html()` returns a string representing the nodes; `.contents()` returns the nodes themselves. One advantage is that events are still bound when you move the nodes. Such information is lost if you convert to and from a string in the process.